# How can I append two lists together? Scheme

Tags: list, append, scheme, lisp, racket

I need help merging two lists together. My goal is to replace `"a"` with `"abc"`. I've already done a counter etc but somehow I can't append these two  lists (list which is an empty list and `'("abc")` as my new list that I want to add).

I've tried to add more brackets but the problem just keeps getting worse the more I add.

```
(define (umwandl tr)
  (cond ((null? tr) (display "Kein Text eingegeben"))
        (else (uff (string->list tr) '()))))  ; string wird nict inliste umgweandel

(define (uff tr liste)
  (cond ((null? tr)(list->string liste))
        (else 
           (cond ((equal? (first (rest (first (start1 (first tr))))) 1)
                    **((append list (list '("abc"))))))**
                    (uff (rest tr) liste))))
```

My error messages are either that `('("abc"))` isn't an argument or it just gives me `""` as an answer. It would be super nice if anyone could help!

Comment: "I've tried to add more brackets but the problem just keeps getting worse the more I add". That sounds like a pretty bad idea. How about studying the syntax and actually _understanding_ where brackets should go in the first place?

Comment: Also, please post a sample input and the expected output for your code. And post your code in English, so more people can understand it.

Comment: `(eq? list liste) ; ==> #f`. Also you are calling the result from `append` as a procedure (double parentheses does that). Things like this you should use `cons` and not `append` or `list` since it confuses you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, luckily I was able to figure it out myself! Also thanks for the tip that I should post my code in English :).

Answer (score 1):

Learning Scheme or any Lisp means getting to know list structure. A list `(1 2 3)` can be made like `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` and I like to think that element in a list that does not have a `.` means there is one and the rest has an extra set of paranthesis. Done recursive! Thus:

```
'(1 2 3)              ; ==
'(1 . (2 3))          ; ==
'(1 . (2 . (3)))      ; ==
'(1 . (2 . (3 . ()))) ; ==> (1 2 3)
```

I see the dots that aren't there when I see lists so I know `3` is `caddr` since I pass `. (` 2 times (`dd`) and then jump into the `car`, thus `caddr`. 
Appending two lists together means copying the first list and replaceing `()` with the **second list**. Thus `append` can be defined as:

```
(define (my-append l1 l2)
  (if (null? l1) 
      l2
      (cons (car l1) 
            (my-append (cdr l1) l2))))
```

Replacing one element with another. You need to do the same BUT you compare the first element in each iteration and based on that either use the element you found or the replacement. If you want to compare strings then you need to use `equal?` since `(eqv? "hello" "hello") ; ==> #f` is a valid result.